# React function displayBanner = () => {

Tags: reactjs

I am currently working on a project and trying to attempt to hide a banner by changing the state of a className like the following:

```
<div className={visbilityBanner}>
```

I have a Hide Banner button like the following:

```
 <button
    type="button"
    className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
    size="small"
    style={hideButtonsStyle}
    onClick={(e) => displayBanner(e)}
    >
       Hide Banner
    </button>
```

My train of thought is the solution needs a function called displayBanner.  In the code below it checks if the !bannerHdr && !bannerMsg (if no text the variables are undefined) then change className = 'hide' the banner else className = 'show'

```
const displayBanner = () => {
    const [visbilityBanner, setVisbilityBanner] = useState('show');

    if (!bannerHdr && !bannerMsg) {                  
      setVisbilityBanner('hide');      
        console.log(visbilityBanner);     
        return visbilityBanner;
    } 
    setVisbilityBanner('show');     
      console.log(visbilityBanner);
      return visbilityBanner;
    };
```

However, I am getting a compile error:

Failed to compile

```
Failed to compile
./src/components/Banners.js
  Line 220:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "displayBanner" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 249:  'visbilityBanner' is not defined                                                                                                         no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Can anyone assist in explaining what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The logic should be a part of the [`style` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style):

```
<HeaderWrapper style={{ visibility: props.isBannerVisible ? 'hidden' : 'none' }}>
```

If you still want to have a function you should return an object instead of a string, so it will match the `style` prop:

```
function hideBanner(isBannerVisible) {
  return { visiblity: isBannerVisible ? "hidden" : "none" };
}

<HeaderWrapper style={{ ...hideBanner(props.isBannerVisible) }} />;
```

Comment: I feel I am close, but I am getting syntax errors on the style attribute ```<HeaderWrapper style={{ height:'110px', hideBanner(props.isBannerVisible) }}" >``` -- Should the function hideBanner(isBanner) be function hideBanner(props) ?

Comment: You already have an example in the answer.

Comment: Dennis Vash I have edited the question in hopes to better clarify a solution.  I am getting a compile error now.

Comment: You should add another question instead of repeatedly updating the question. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for the advice I will ask another question.

Comment: Added new question that supersedes this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65667839/react-function-displaybanner-compile-issue