# React function displayBanner compile issue

Tags: reactjs

I am currently working on a project and trying to hide a banner by changing the state of a `className` like the following:

```
<div className={visbilityBanner}>
```

I have a `Hide Banner` button like the following:

```
 <button
    type="button"
    className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
    size="small"
    style={hideButtonsStyle}
    onClick={(e) => displayBanner(e)}
    >
       Hide Banner
    </button>
```

My train of thought is the solution needs a function called `displayBanner`.  In the code below I check if the `!bannerHdr && !bannerMsg` (if no text the variables are `undefined`) then change `className = 'hide'` else change to `className = 'show'`

```
const displayBanner = () => {
    const [visbilityBanner, setVisbilityBanner] = useState('show');

    if (!bannerHdr && !bannerMsg) {                  
      setVisbilityBanner('hide');      
        console.log(visbilityBanner);     
        return visbilityBanner;
    } 
    setVisbilityBanner('show');     
      console.log(visbilityBanner);
      return visbilityBanner;
    };
```

However, I am getting a compile error:

Failed to compile

```
Failed to compile
./src/components/Banners.js
  Line 220:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "displayBanner" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 249:  'visbilityBanner' is not defined                                                                                                         no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Can anyone assist in explaining what I am missing?

Comment: Can you show a full minimal reproducible example: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of sharing snippets.

Comment: Please read about custom hooks, you can't write a function (which is not a custom hook) using hooks as part of Rules of Hooks, as stated in the error.

Comment: Dennis as soon as I moved the  constant declaration outside of the arrow function it worked - const [visbilityBanner, setVisbilityBanner] = useState('show');  I am a bit confused because I taking a GREAT COURSE on Udemy and it shows them declaring these inside of functions and not having compile issues.  I am not saying it is right or wrong, but it is now working.  I will post back with the response from Udemy I have the same question posted on there Q&A board for the course.

Comment: Dennis I am also providing as much code without over stepping company policy.  I apologize about the snippets.  I do not want to expose something that is classified as internal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `React Hooks` in Top level of a Component not inside a `function or if block`, change your code to this and you're good to go:

```
const [visbilityBanner, setVisbilityBanner] = useState("show");

const displayBanner = () => {
  if (!bannerHdr && !bannerMsg) {
    setVisbilityBanner("hide");
    console.log(visbilityBanner);
    return visbilityBanner;
  }
  setVisbilityBanner("show");
  console.log(visbilityBanner);
  return visbilityBanner;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is giving an error is because `displayBanner` is a function and not a React Component. React components ALWAYS return jsx. That function is only returning the `show` or `hide` strings. In that case, it is just a helper function and you cannot use the `useState` hook.

Given the answer for the errors, here's a different implementation for that:

```
 const App = () => {
   const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);
   
   return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setIsVisible(false)}>Click to hide</button>

        {isVisible && <Banner />}

      </div>
    )
}
```